# Is there a compatibility issue between python arcade 2.4a5 and Spyder 4.0.1?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, arcade

Howdy fellow overflowers,

Ive had a hankering to build a simple platformer using python! The search led me to python arcade! While going through the tutorial here: https://opensource.com/article/18/4/easy-2d-game-creation-python-and-arcade

my pop up window refuses to load and forces me to close the program (python) when all I have is this peice of code:

```
arcade.open_window(screen_width,screen_height,'Drawing Example');
```

Here is an image of the resulting pop up window:

[image: The resulting pop window upon execution of aforementioned line of code]

Is it an issue with Spyder, should I use another IDE?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following to run your application:

```
arcade.run()
```

Comment: Its been a while , but thanks for answering this question. I will give it a go!